# Default memory request with possibility of override in a Snakefile?

Tags: snakemake

I have a Snakefile with several rules and only a few need more than 1 GB/core to run on a cluster. The `resources` directive is great for this, but I can't find a way of setting a default value. I would prefer not having to write `resources: mem_per_cpu = 1024` for every rule that doesn't need more than the default.

I realize that I could get what I want using `__default__` in a [cluster config file](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#cluster-configuration) and overriding the `mem_per_cpu` value for specific rules. I hesitate to do this because the memory requirements are platform-independent, so I would prefer including them in the Snakefile itself. It would also prevent me from being able to specify local resource limits using the `--resources` command-line option.

Is there a simple solution with Snakemake that would help me here? Thanks!

Comment: Found your post right after posting mine - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47600510/3998252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading the [changelog](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#id1) of the Snakemake and I came across this:

> Add –default-resources flag, that allows to define default resources
>   for jobs (e.g. mem_mb, disk_mb), see docs.

Comment: I haven't tested this option yet, but I'll mark this as the answer until I'm told otherwise. Thanks for posting this here!