# Snakemake - Override LSF (bsub) cluster config in a rule-specific manner

Tags: configuration, cluster-computing, snakemake

Is it possible to define default settings for memory and resources in cluster config file, and then override in rule specific manner, when needed? Is `resources` field in rules directly tied to cluster config file? Or is it just a fancy way for `params` field for readability purposes?

In the example below, how do I use default cluster configs for `rule a`, but use custom changes (`memory=40000` and `rusage=15000`) in `rule b`?

**cluster.json:**

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
        "memory": 20000,
        "resources": "\"rusage[mem=8000] span[hosts=1]\"",
        "output": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    },
}
```

**Snakefile:**

```
rule all:
    'a_out.txt', 'b_out.txt'

rule a:
    input:
        'a.txt'
    output:
        'a_out.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'

rule b:
    input:
        'b.txt'
    output:
        'b_out.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```

**Command for execution:**

```
 snakemake --cluster-config cluster.json 
           --cluster "bsub -M {cluster.memory} -R {cluster.resources} -o logs.txt" 
           -j 50
```

I understand that it is possible to define rule specific resources requirements in cluster config file, but I would prefer to define them directly in Snakefile, if possible.

Or else, if there is a better way of implementing this, please let me know.

Comment: Found this related post just after I posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45111823/3998252. I am not deleting my post as this question shows few more details with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add `resources` to each of your rules :

```
rule all:
    'a_out.txt' , 'b_out.txt'

rule a:
    input:
        'a.txt'
    output:
        'a_out.txt'
    resources:
        mem_mb=40000
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
rule b:
    input:
        'b.txt'
    output:
        'b_out.txt'
    resources:
        mem_mb=20000
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```

And then, you should remove the `resources` parameter from your `.json`, so that the command line would not override the snakefile:

**new.cluster.json:**

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
        "output": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    },
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to set default resource constraints in cluster config file and then changing them when needed in Snakefile in rule specific manner. Idea being here is that I would need to change resources only rarely. With that said, I have been pondering lately on implementing what you described here. I would prefer the former for the sake of reducing verbosity, but it could also be argued that all about rules are kept in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

In `new.cluster.json` you can actually define resources for specific rules. So in your case you would do the following

```
{
    "__default__":
    {
        "memory": 20000,
        "resources": "\"rusage[mem=8000] span[hosts=1]\"",
        "output": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    },
    "b":
    {
        "memory": 40000,
        "resources": "\"rusage[mem=15000] span[hosts=1]\"",
        "output": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.out",
        "error": "logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards}.err"
    },
}
```

Then in the `Snakefile` you can refer to these resources by importing `new.cluster.json` and referring to it in your rule

```
import json

with open('new.cluster.json') as fh:
    cluster_config = json.load(fh)

rule all:
    'a_out.txt' , 'b_out.txt'

rule a:
    input:
        'a.txt'
    output:
        'a_out.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
rule b:
    input:
        'b.txt'
    output:
        'b_out.txt'
    resources:
        mem_mb=cluster_config["b"]["memory"]
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```

If you take a look through [this repository](https://github.com/iqbal-lab-org/Mykrobe_tb_workflow), you can see how I use these cluster configs in the wild.